# IF Else in stored procedures not working

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

```
CREATE PROCEDURE p1 
(
    IN name_val VARCHAR(255),
    OUT iJobID  INT
)


BEGIN

    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM test WHERE id='11')

        BEGIN

            INSERT INTO test(name) VALUES(name_val);
            SET iJobID :=  LAST_INSERT_ID();
        END

    ELSE
        BEGIN

             UPDATE test SET name=name_val WHERE id = 11; 
        END 

    INSERT INTO vasu2(vname) VALUES(name_val);
    SET @ivD :=  LAST_INSERT_ID();

    INSERT INTO vasu(id, id2) VALUES(iJobID, @ivD); 
END;
```

Comment: strange, this looks more like TSQL/MSSQL than mysql... maybe this is already your problem. stored procedures ARE NOT interchangeable between different database systems

Comment: What does it mean "not working"? Is it show any error, do not do what you want or anything else

Comment: Can you describe errors that you receive during run?

Comment: hi Valex this is the error message: Stored procedure creation failed: (1064) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BEGIN INSERT INTO test(name) VALUES(name_val); SET iJobID := LAST_INSER' at line 8

Comment: You need to finish your IF statement with an `END IF;`.

Comment: @fedorqui getting same error..!! Thanks for response

Comment: r u exec-ing on the right DB

Comment: INSERT INTO \`test\`(\`name\`) VALUES(name_val);

Comment: yes, i'm executing in correct DB , issue is here IF ELSE when i run with out if else is executes perfectly.. with out any error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `IF` syntax you are using is most likely for `T-SQL`. Also, you need to change the `delimiter`.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE p1 
(
    IN name_val VARCHAR(255),
    OUT iJobID  INT
)
BEGIN

    SET @recCount := (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test WHERE id = 11);
    IF @recCount > 0 THEN
        INSERT INTO test(name) VALUES(name_val);
        SET iJobID :=  LAST_INSERT_ID();
    ELSE
        UPDATE test SET name=name_val WHERE id = 11; 
    END IF;

    INSERT INTO vasu2(vname) VALUES(name_val);
    SET @ivD :=  LAST_INSERT_ID();

    INSERT INTO vasu(id, id2) VALUES(iJobID, @ivD); 
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

- [Using Stored Procedures](http://www.brainbell.com/tutorials/MySQL/Using_Stored_Procedures.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot about: `delimiter`, `then`, `end if`
Hope it helps

```
delimiter $$


CREATE PROCEDURE test.p1 
(
    IN name_val VARCHAR(255),
    OUT iJobID  INT
)
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM test WHERE id='11') THEN
            INSERT INTO test(name) VALUES(name_val);
            SET iJobID :=  LAST_INSERT_ID();
    ELSE
             UPDATE test SET name=name_val WHERE id = 11; 
    END IF;
    INSERT INTO vasu2(vname) VALUES(name_val);
    SET @ivD :=  LAST_INSERT_ID();
    INSERT INTO vasu(id, id2) VALUES(iJobID, @ivD); 
END
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

i think IF not exists does not exist in mysql then